# dotenv variables 'undefined' when used inside an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

Using nodejs with dotenv for secrets.

Following code:

```
var tokenForm = {
    grant_type: 'password',
    username: process.env.USERNAME,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD
};

console.log(tokenForm)
```

results in undefined

```
 { grant_type: 'password', username: undefined, password: undefined }
```

However, when I log individual variables directly, it works!

```
console.log(process.env.USERNAME);
console.log(process.env.PASSWORD);
```

Output:

```
my_username
my_password
```

How I get the code to evaluate the dotenv vars when using them inside of the object?

Answer (score 0):

Before use your env vars, you must load dot env.

[More information in documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

```
require('dotenv').config()
```